# Sql server LIKE Operator with comma separated string

Tags: sql-server

My stored procedure receives a parameter which is a comma-separated string:

```
DECLARE  @review_status varchar(200)
SET @review_status='CANCELLED,INSPECTED,REJECTED,UNASSIGNED'
```

I use this variable with **LIKE** Operator, when value without comma then perfect but it comes with comma then unable to handle.
Now i use this statement

```
SELECT * FROM tblReview WHERE 
review_status LIKE '%' + @review_status + '%'
```

I need to make from it this statement

```
SELECT * FROM tblReview WHERE 
review_status LIKE '%CANCELLED%' OR --Pass @review_status
review_status LIKE '%INSPECTED%' OR 
review_status LIKE '%REJECTED%'.....
```

What is the best practice for doing this?

Comment: Strictly speaking, I would say that best practice would be to use a table valued parameter instead of a scalar.  Any time you're breaking first normal form, you're probably not following best practice.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a string splitter to do this. Read this [**article**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) for one of the fastest splitter there is.

Then you need to use the `IN` operator to do the filtering:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblReview 
WHERE review_status IN(
    SELECT item FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@review_status,',')
)
```

---

Since you're using `LIKE`, you may want to do `JOIN` instead of `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblReview t
INNER JOIN dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@review_status, ',') s
    ON t.review_status LIKE '%' + s.Item + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to first convert varchar with commas to a table as described here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitjet/archive/2009/12/11/sql-server-comma-separated-string-to-table.aspx. Then, use the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #allPattern (
  pattern NVARCHAR(max)
);

INSERT INTO #allPattern VALUES ('%CANCELLED%'), ('%INSPECTED%'), ('%REJECTED%');

SELECT t.* FROM tblReview t JOIN #allPattern a ON (t.review_status LIKE a.pattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the pre- and trailing comma to yous string, and then use `CHARINDEX()`.

```
SET @review_status=',CANCELLED,INSPECTED,REJECTED,UNASSIGNED,'
SELECT * FROM tblReview WHERE 
charindex(','+review_status+',', '@review_status') >0
```

Commas at the beginning and at the end of the string are used to make an exact string finding possible - for example, if you have two statuses - one called CAN and the second called CANCELLED, charindex without side commas will find them both.

It's the simplest way, but not the one with the best performance, so don't use it on long CSVs.